# CRM 2011: Limitation of query expression?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I believe the answer to this question may be to use Linq to Sql, but wanted to see if this is something which is possible using QueryExpressions:-

I create a query expression which queries against Entity A, it also links to Entity B (via LinkEntity) and imposes additional criteria. It is possible to retrieve columns from Entity B by adding the appropriate attribute names. However, it will only retrieve the linked entity (inner join).

Is it possible using QueryExpression to retrieve all related records (and required columns) from Entity B related to Entity A (e.g. all cases associated with contact where contact passes specified criteria). Normally I would consider inverting the query and searching for Entity B relatig to Entity A with the appropriate LinkEntity Conditions, but there are a number of linked entities which I would like to retrieve for the same contact query.

So I'm left with some options:-

(1) Perform a second query (not ideal when iterating over a large number of results from the initial query),
(2) Perform a query using Linq to CRM on the filtered views,
(3) A different method entirely?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I ended up using Linq-to-Sql to complete this task and the code used is similar to that below (albeit with a few more joins for the actual query!):-

```
var dataCollection = (from eA in xrmServiceContext.EntityASet

join eB in xrmServiceContext.EntityBSet on new  EntityReference(EntityA.EntityLogicalName, eA.Id) equals (EntityReference)eB.EntityBLookupToEntityA
select new
{
    Id = eA.Id,
    EntityBInterestingAttribute = eB.InterestingAttributeName 
}
```

So this will bring back a row per Entity A, per Entity B. To make things easier I then defined a custom class "MyEntityAClass" which had properties which were Lists so I could return one object for filling of GridView etc. This is more to do with the processing of these results though so I haven't posted that code here.

I hope that makes sense. Essentially, it is getting the multiple rows per record a la SQL which makes this method work.

Comment: I'm sure its just me, but I dont understand what query you are trying to make? Can you make the query you want in SQL? Left outer joins are supported by QueryExpression so that might be what you need?

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your comment. I am able to perform the query in SQL using inner joins and I retrieve the expected number of rows, e.g. selecting from Entity A set and joining to Entity B on the lookup attribute. But with the query expression if I attempt to retrieve columns from Entity B I am only able to retrieve columns from one of the N matching records in Entity B. So the problem doesn't lie so much with the linking, but the ability to retrieve the required attributes from the related records when there exist more than one of them (same entity alias and attribute name).

Comment: If that's still not clear ( I can understand if it is not :)) I'll post a code scenario when I'm back on my other machine later.

Comment: I think I understand. So you only get one row per A even thought it joins to many Bs? Im suprised it does not return duplicate A rows, one for each B (like SQL does). Maybe Im still misunderstanding...

Comment: Agreed. I think what may be happening is that it is actually returning multiple rows, but because of the way that the linkEntities[0].AddColumns is working with its alias it is only storing the last value. I have subsequently completed the query I require using linq-to-sql, however, it would be good to understand if this is a genuine limitation or if there is an alternative syntax or workaround.

Comment: @PhilipRich: Can you post your Linq query that you ended up using?

Comment: @PeterMajeed Hi Peter, I have edited the original post with a code sample (where I have replaced the actual entity names with monikers). Hope is helps.

Comment: @PhilipRich I do this in one of my services to retrieve all Names associated to a Customer (such as Legal, AKA, Previous name); and I do in fact, receive multiple rows per Customer.  Assuming this is still a question, you might need to share real code.

Answer (score -4):

QueryExpression can only return fields from one type of entity, the one specified in QueryExpression.EntityName.

You can use FetchXML which allows you to also get the fields of any link entities, which would be an option 3 for you, unfortunately it returns the data as XML which you would then have to parse yourself.

It might be quicker to run the FetchXML, but it will take longet to write and test, and its not the easiest thing to maintain either.

Sample Code, this gets the first 101 of all Cases that are active for all accounts that are active

```
string fetch = "<fetch count='101' mapping='logical'><entity name='account'><filter type='and'><condition attribute='statecode' operator='eq' value='1'/></filter><link-entity name='incident' from='customerid' to='accountid'><all-attributes/><filter type='and'><condition attribute='statecode' operator='eq' value='1'/></filter></link-entity></entity></fetch>";

string data = yourCrmServiceObject.Fetch(fetch);
```

Comment: *"QueryExpression can only return fields from one type of entity, the one specified in QueryExpression.EntityName."* This is plainly wrong. You can have LinkEntity and its attributes in a QueryExpression just the same as in FetchXml.